# 404 Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Estoy practicando con Spring JPA. Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/empleados")
public class EmpleadoController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("empleadoRepository")
    private EmpleadoRepository empleadoRepository;

    @GetMapping("/listarempleados")
    public ModelAndView listarEmpleados() {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("listaempleados");
        mav.addObject("empleados", empleadoRepository.findEmpleadoByAge());
        return mav;

    }
}
```

Dentro de mi carpeta src/main/resources tengo una carpeta templates con el nombre listaempleados.html pero al acceder a la url *http://localhost:8080/empleados/listarempleados* me arroja que no encuentra la pagina.

¿He configurado mal mi ModelAndView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi clase principal, donde se encuentra la etiqueta **@SpringBootApplication** agregue la siguiente **@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.ejemplo"})** y ahora funciona.